# Force quit app under test without crashing test process

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm running some UI tests (espresso + ui automator). I want to test the app being restarted in the background by the system. Most things I've read suggest using `android.os.Process.killProcess(processid);`

I have this method running in my test class :

```
public void forceQuit() {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    int processid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
        if (info.processName.equals("com.example.debug")) {
            Log.d("TAG, ", "ABOUT TO FORCE QUIT: " + info.processName);
            processid = info.pid;
        }
    }

    if (processid != 0) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(processid);
    }
}
```

The problem is that both the app and the instrumentation are running in the same process. Is there any other way to do this without crashing the entire test?

UPDATE:

As @CommonsWare pointed out this isn't how Android really handles. I should have known that from the logs:

```
2018-09-18 17:13:13.858 30357-30445/com.example.debug D/TAG,: ABOUT TO FORCE QUIT
2018-09-18 17:13:13.859 30357-30445/com.example.debug I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30357 SIG: 9
...
2018-09-18 17:13:13.904 3238-5855/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{74da2c7 u0 com.example.debug/com.example.main.MainActivity}
...
2018-09-18 17:13:13.905 3238-30027/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.debug (pid 30357) has died: fore TOP 
2018-09-18 17:13:13.907 3238-30027/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.debug/com.example.MyOtherService in 1000ms
2018-09-18 17:13:13.908 3238-30027/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.debug/com.example.MyService in 10998ms
2018-09-18 17:13:13.908 3238-30027/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{e29eba9 u0 com.example.debug/com.example.main.MainActivity t12323}: app died, no saved state
2018-09-18 17:13:13.909 3238-3292/? W/zygote64: kill(-30357, 9) failed: No such process
...
2018-09-18 17:13:13.916 3238-4737/? W/WindowManager: removeWindowToken: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@a45bb61
...
2018-09-18 17:13:13.921 3238-30027/? W/ActivityManager: Crash of app com.example.debug running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.example.debug.test/com.example.e2etests.E2ETestRunner}
2018-09-18 17:13:13.921 3238-30027/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.debug appid=10686 user=0: finished inst
2018-09-18 17:13:13.922 3238-30630/? W/Binder: Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
    java.lang.Throwable
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:752)
        at android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher$Stub$Proxy.instrumentationFinished(IInstrumentationWatcher.java:160)
        at com.android.server.am.InstrumentationReporter$MyThread.run(InstrumentationReporter.java:86)
2018-09-18 17:13:13.924 3238-30027/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{1efa5d5 u0 com.example.debug/com.example.MyOtherService}
2018-09-18 17:13:13.924 3238-30027/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{16f8bbd u0 com.example.debug/com.example.MyService}
```

Comment: "Most things I've read suggest using android.os.Process.killProcess(processid)" -- that does not specifically simulate the behavior of Android terminating a background process. "Is there any other way to do this without crashing the entire test?" -- not using instrumented tests.

Comment: thx. I should have known Android didn't work that way. I can see some "crash" in logs when I do this. Yeah I was hoping to rely on my existing test code to do this. Aside from a purely human-run test, do you know of any other framework that can do this?

Comment: It's unlikely that you will find anything suitable. The test code would have to run in a separate process (`monkeyrunner`, possibly Appium and similar solutions, etc.). But the test code would also need to be able to kill your process (`adb` with emulators, not possible with un-rooted hardware). And then the test code would somehow need to restart and re-connect to the app. And none of that may actually test the relevant scenario: what it is like when Android terminates the background process due to low memory conditions.